# Croogo auth error on form crarting

Tags: croogo

I am making my own users add form with croogo users plugin.
when I try to make my own fields, it gives me error/

```
Security Error
The requested address was not found on this server.

Request blackholed due to "auth" violation.
```

whats the reason for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a forgotten `Form::end()`, a `<select>` with no options, or even a simple syntax error, or anything really.

I suggested in http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.cms.croogo/598 to try sticking $this->log(Debugger::trace()) in CroogoAppController::blackHoleCallback()
then go through the stacktrace (in tmp/logs/error.log) and see what's going on.

Or turn off Security component temporarily to debug the problem.